# Keep cookie for all the request in my app when using volley

Tags: android, cookies

I am using volley in my android application and I use it to load images most of the time, however once I have to download some file(not images) I use native `HttpURLConnection` instead of volley.

Now I want both the volley and the `HttpURLConnection` will use the same cookie in my whole application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `VolleyRequest` class that extends the `com.android.volley.Request`. All your requests in the app will be using this class.

To use the cookie with all these requests override the `getHeaders` method and you can do the same operation of setting the cookie as you might be doing with `HttpURLConnection`

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
   HashMap<String, String> headersMap =  new HashMap<String, String>();
   headersMap.put("Cookie", "COOKIE_KEY=COOKIE_VALUE");
   return headersMap;
}
```